# Mininet topology with OpendayLight remote controller- got very low bandwidth on iperf test

Tags: mininet, opendaylight, iperf

I run a mininet topology (of type "tree" but this happens to me also in custom topology without special link configure) that connects to the remote controller- ODL.

when I run "iperf" test, I get bandwidth of like 100-200 Mbps.

when I run the same topology with other controllers (POX, Floodlight, default controller of mininet) I get bandwidth of 25-30 **Gbps**!!!

I can't figure out why, I try to check for unique configuration in ODL, try to re-install, try different versions (Carbon and Beryllium), but nothing.

Please, help me!

some pictures:

mininet tree topology with default controller get high bandwidth:
**Screenshot**
[image]

mininet tree topo with ODL gets low bandwidth:
**Screenshot**
[image]

"mininet> dpctl dump-ports-desc" (to show the ports in the switch are 10G):
**Screenshot**
[image]

"http://192.168.56.103:8181/restconf/operational/opendaylight-inventory:nodes"  (show in the controller that he sees 10G ports)
**Screenshot**
[image]

the ODL feature:list -install I have:
**Screenshot**
[image]

**Screenshot**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've probably missed something but unless you have a physical network >> 25 Gbit/s, (and you suggest  your physical network is 10 Gbit/s) those 25 Gbit/s results you are getting may be tests running over loopback and not actually leaving the physical hardware.